# Replace the ref of a parameter without using the ref keyword (using IL)

Tags: c#, cil, il, ref, dynamicmethod

I am looking to be able to replace the object reference of a parameter without having to use the ref keyword.

The reason that I am avoiding using ref is to preserve collection initializer invocation which looks for an `Add(T item)` method, and I need to have the collection class replace the reference with a different implementation of it's interface.

I have tried a couple of different ways to of doing this. First I tried using the undocumented keywords `__makeref`, `__refvalue` and `__reftype`.

Secondly I tried to create a `DynamicMethod` with some IL that tried to mimic what I observed from looking at a disassembled similar call with a ref parameter.

Here is some code to demonstrate:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Reflection.Emit;
using System.Reflection;
interface IRecord
{
    string Name { get;}
}
class ImpA : IRecord
{
    public string Name { get { return "Implementation A"; } }
}
class ImpB : IRecord
{
    public string Name { get { return "Implementation B"; } }
}
class RecordList<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    //// Standard Add method (of course does not work)
    //public void Add(T item)
    //{
    //    item = (T)(object)new ImpB();
    //}

    // ref method (works great but the signature cannot be
    // used by the collection initializer)
    public void Add(ref T item)
    {
        IRecord newItem = new ImpB();
        item = (T)newItem;
    }

    //// Using System.TypedReference (does not work)
    //public void Add(T item)
    //{
    //    T newItem = (T)(object)new ImpB();
    //    TypedReference typedRef = __makeref(item);
    //    __refvalue(typedRef, T) = newItem;
    //}

    // Using Reflection.Emit DynamicMethod (This method should work but I need help)
    public void Add(T item)
    {
        IRecord newItem = new ImpB();

        System.Reflection.MethodAttributes methodAttributes =
              System.Reflection.MethodAttributes.Public
            | System.Reflection.MethodAttributes.Static;

        DynamicMethod dm = new DynamicMethod("AssignRef",
            methodAttributes,
            CallingConventions.Standard,
            null,
            new Type[] { typeof(IRecord), typeof(IRecord) },
            this.GetType(),
            true);

        ILGenerator generator = dm.GetILGenerator();
        // IL of method
        //public static void Add(ref item, ref newItem)
        //{
        //    item = newItem;
        //}
        // -- Loading Params (before call to Add() --
        //L_002b: ldloca.s sb // this is the ref variable
        //L_002d: ldloc.2 // The other variable
        // -- Add method IL --
        //L_0000: nop 
        //L_0001: ldarg.0 
        //L_0002: ldarg.1 
        //L_0003: stind.ref 
        //L_0004: ret 

        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarga_S, 0);
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Stind_Ref);
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        Action<IRecord, IRecord> AssignRef =
            (Action<IRecord, IRecord>)dm.CreateDelegate(
            typeof(Action<IRecord, IRecord>));

        AssignRef((IRecord)item, (IRecord)newItem);
    }


    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    IEnumerator<T> IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IRecord imp = new ImpA();
        Console.WriteLine("Original implementation: {0}\n", imp.Name);

        // Calls Add Implicitly
        RecordList<IRecord> records = new RecordList<IRecord> { imp };
        // Prints "Implementation A"
        Console.WriteLine("After Add Method: {0}", imp.Name);

        records.Add(ref imp); // Explicit call with ref
        // Prints "Implementation B"
        Console.WriteLine("After Add Ref method: {0}\n", imp.Name);
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: You're trying to make something truly ugly. Are you sure you need/want this?

Comment: The code snippet I posted is only for demonstrating a concept which helps explain my question. I realize that it could be used to create something ugly though - thanks.

Answer (score 8):

> I am looking to be able to replace the object reference of a parameter without having to use the ref keyword.

This is simply not going to happen; when your (non-`ref`) method is called, the CLR creates a copy of the passed reference, which your method receives. While your method can modify that reference to its heart's content, it has **absolutely no access** to the reference from which the copy was made (the reference that was passed in by the calling method) no matter what trickery you attempt using undocumented keywords or clever CIL.

*Also, why you're trying to replace parameters passed into a collection initializer is beyond me. It smells of code that does things it shouldn't.*

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I thought this be accomplished in managed c++ (am I wrong?). So how could it be a limitation of the CLR? If I am using an interface, why should switching the implementation be a problem?

Comment: I don't know of a language that allows functions to modify a non-reference parameter. This can't be done in .NET (as it's not supported by the CLR) which means it can't be done in Managed C++ or C++/CLI.

Comment: As this answer points out, the OPs goal as stated is inherently nonsensical. The very reason things are passed by reference is to... well, allow reference to them.